# Symfony2: why access_denied_handler doesn't work

Tags: symfony, exception

I want to customize the behavior of Symfony2 in case of AccessDeniedException.
If the HTTP request which raises the exception is an XMLHTTPRequest then I reply with a JSON otherwise I generate a 302 found to the login page.

Here's my implementation. The log shows that AccessDeneidHandler is never called after an AccessDeniedException. What am I missing ?

```
#security.yml
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        access_denied_handler: kernel.listener.access_denied.handler
```

```
#config.yml
kernel.listener.access_denied.handler:
   class: NoaLisa\Bundle\OVMBundle\DependencyInjection\AccessDeniedHandler
     tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.kernel_response, method: handle}
```

```
#AccessDeniedHandler

class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface{

function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException){

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('status' => 'protected')));
        return $response;
    }
    else {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok finally I found out what was the problem when I dig into ExceptionListener

The service pointed by `access_denied_handler` is only called if the user has insufficient privilege to access the resource. If the user is not authenticated at all access_dened_handler is never called.

Providing a service to `entry_point` in `security.yml` did actually solve the problem.

Comment: for anyone who found this answer lacking here is the laid out solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428987/what-is-the-best-way-to-notify-a-user-after-an-access-control-rule-redirects/17432089#17432089

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to figure out why accessing a controller with @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')") was not triggering the handler when $this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') was true. So the handler is also not called for users authenticated from REMEMBER_ME and accessing resources requiring full authentication. Thanks!