# What is the best way to notify a user after an access_control rule redirects?

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, twig, access-control

From [Symfony 2.3 Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#understanding-how-access-control-works) docs:

> If access is denied, **the system will try to authenticate the user if not already (e.g. redirect the user to the login page)**. If the user is already logged in, the 403 "access denied" error page will be shown. See How to customize Error Pages for more information.

I am currently using an `access_control` rule for a few routes. I would like to notify an anonymous user if they're redirected to the login route with a message like "*You must login to access that page*." I have read through the Security docs a few times and haven't found anything relevant to this. Am I overlooking something?

If not, what would be the best way to notify the user when they're stopped by an `access_control` rule **only** if they're redirected to login (ie not if they're just in an *unauthorized role*)?

**EDIT:**
For clarification, I am specifically asking how to check if a redirect was caused by an `access_control` rule (preferably in twig if possible).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

So after quite a bit of research, I found the right way to do this. You'll need to use an [Entry Point](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points) service and define it in your firewall configuration.

This method **will not mess** with your [default page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page) settings specified in your firewall config for logging in.

---

## The Code

**security.yml:**

```
firewalls:
    main:
        entry_point: entry_point.user_login #or whatever you name your service
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
        # ...
```

**src/Acme/UserBundle/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    entry_point.user_login:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Service\LoginEntryPoint
        arguments: [ @router ] #I am going to use this for URL generation since I will be redirecting in my service
```

**src/Acme/UserBundle/Service/LoginEntryPoint.php:**

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * When the user is not authenticated at all (i.e. when the security context has no token yet), 
 * the firewall's entry point will be called to start() the authentication process. 
 */
class LoginEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct($router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /*
     * This method receives the current Request object and the exception by which the exception 
     * listener was triggered. 
     * 
     * The method should return a Response object
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // I am choosing to set a FlashBag message with my own custom message.
        // Alternatively, you could use AuthenticationException's generic message 
        // by calling $authException->getMessage()
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'You must be logged in to access that page');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));
    }
}
```

**login.html.twig:**

```
{# bootstrap ready for your convenience ;] #}
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('warning') %}
    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('warning') %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            {{ flashMessage }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

## Resources:

- [AuthenticationEntryPointInterface API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/EntryPoint/AuthenticationEntryPointInterface.html)
- [Entry Points Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points)
- [Security Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)
- [How to Customize your Form Login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#)
- [Why access_denied_handle doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968354/symfony2-why-access-denied-handler-doesnt-work) *- thanks to [cheesemacfly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443490/cheesemacfly) for [tip](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10341330#10341330)*

Comment: Nice one Carrie, what a nightmare!

Comment: Good job. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Not exactly what I was aiming for, but nevertheless, so helpful for a similar problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think a [`kernel.exception`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-kernel-exception) listener and setting a flash message can do it. Untested example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class My403ExceptionListener
{
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('warning', 'You must login to access that page.');
        }
    }
}
```

Don't really know if it works or if it's the right thing. You can register it as `kernel.event_listener`. Or maybe it's better you wright a dedicated service and set it as the parameter of `access_denied_handler` in the [firewall config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html). I think there a many possible ways.

Comment: the access_denied_handler is never fired for redirects, only unauthorized

Comment: yeah it was very obfuscated in the search results and the documentation's description of it is very minimal. I might submit a patch

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just have two login routes?

For example, in security config set

```
form_login:
    login_path: /login_message
```

In your login controller

```
/**
 * @Template()
 * @Route("/notauthorized", name="login_message")
 */
 public function loginMessageAction()
 {
    return [];
 }
```

And then in your loginMessage.html.twg

```
<a href="{{ path('login') }}">You must login to access this page.</a>
```

Comment: although this is a possibility, I am specifically looking for a way that deals with access_control rules. This is a workaround, but not really a solution

Comment: yeah I kind of felt the same way when I wrote it. I am sure there is a "non hackish" way to do it, im just not sure how

Comment: check my answer for a clean hack-free solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm following different approach, in controller I'm throwing new `AuthenticationException` and before that adding error message in flashbag.

```
// Check if user is logged in.
if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') == FALSE) {
  $request->getSession()
    ->getFlashBag()
    ->add('error', "Please login to continue");
  throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

And in login twig template, showing messages.

```
{% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('error') %}
  <div class="callout alert" role="alert">
    {{ flash_message }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```