# SF2: Secure route and deny access through exception instead of redirect to login

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm working on a Symfony 2.4.4 project and I would like to secure an url through security.yml. Symfony default behaviour is to deny access and redirect to login but i would like to through an exception. Does any one know how should i accomplish it?

I'm talking about sonata login route /admin/login, I want to through an exception when unauthenticated users try to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Entry Point option in a firewal - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points

This question/answer may have the information you need - [What is the best way to notify a user after an access_control rule redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428987/what-is-the-best-way-to-notify-a-user-after-an-access-control-rule-redirects/17432089#17432089)

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to give it a try. I was thinking about using access_denied_handler which may also do the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: According to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968354/symfony2-why-access-denied-handler-doesnt-work `access_denied_handler` may not be called every time.