# Symfony2 Firewall: Redirect to registration form instead of login

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I am working on a simple shop (to compile offers) based on Symfony2.

After adding items to his cart, a user can proceed to a summary of his offer and then request the compiled offer.

The summary page is protected by the following firewall:

```
security:
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: default
        form_login:
            login_path: acme_security_login_route
            check_path: acme_security_login_check_route
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout: ~

    default:
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/request-offer, roles: ROLE_CLIENT }

providers:
    default:
        entity: { class: AcmeShopBundle:User }

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Acme\ShopBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost:      15
```

This means that if the client is logged in, he will directly get to the summary, and if not, he is redirected to the login page.

Now as it is more probable for the client to be a new customer I would like to redirect to the registration form, instead.

The options described in the [SecurityBundle Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) don't allow this.
Of course changing the `login_path` is also not a solution.

What would be the nicest possible solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nextar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24373134/2524503) lead me to the solution.

Quoting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968354/symfony2-why-access-denied-handler-doesnt-work):

> the service pointed by access_denied_handler is only called if the user has unsufficient privilege to access the resource. If the user is not authenticated at all access_dened_handler is never called. Providing a service to entry_point in security.yml did actually solve the problem

So I ended up with this:

```yaml
#services.yml
acme.security.entry_point.class: ArtCube\ShopBundle\Service\EntryPointHandler

services:
    acme.security.entry_point_handler:
        class: %acme.security.entry_point.class%
        arguments:
            router:      @router
```

Then I added this service to my `security.yml`, right after `logout: ~` line (see initial question):

```
entry_point: art_cube_shop.security.entry_point_handler
```

And created the service:

```
// Acme/ShopBundle/Service/EntryPointHandler.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InsufficientAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class EntryPointHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface {

    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        if($authException instanceof InsufficientAuthenticationException)
        {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('acme_security_registration_route'));
        } 
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('acme_security_login_route'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion a nice solution is to add an own AccessDeniedExceptionHandler, how to do this is explained here.

[Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface)

Further more, you could made the service configurable via the Configuration Component, so that you pass as argument the route to redirect.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html

If you do this you can change, if you got more users, to redirect back to login page without editing any class.

Comment: access_denied_handler is only called if the user has unsufficient privilege to access the resource, but not if he is not authenticated at all. 

But your answer lead me to the solution, thanks for that!