# Show flashbag message by required user role

Tags: security, symfony, access-control

When I secure a certain area of my Symfony2 project by the firewall, people are being redirected to the login page. How can I display a dynamic message on that login page, that tells the user about the required user role?

E.g. there are four different pages on my project

- `/` is not restricted,
- `/admin` requires `ROLE_ADMIN`,
- `/user` requires `ROLE_USER`,
- `/beta` requires `ROLE_BETA_USER`.

If the user tries to access `/beta`, above the login page there shall be the information

> This area is restricted to beta users.

... and accordingly for `/admin` and `/user`. Is there a way to set this message globally (without having to set it on each controller action separately)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by implementing [`AccessDeniedHandlerInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authorization/AccessDeniedHandlerInterface.html).

In `handle` method you can check request path and add appropriate flash message.

You will have to register your AccessDeniedHandler service in `security.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            access_denied_handler: my.access_denied_handler_service_name
```

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll have a look on that!

Comment: Can you provide examples of the service definition and the handler class? I'm at a loss here...

Comment: This is what I tried: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/536e142c5bc49d3927c8 but I simply get redirected to login without any handling by my service.

Comment: Complete example: http://www.alexfu.it/2012/11/09/force-incomplete-users-to-complete-registration.html

Comment: That's the example I applied, just taking out the service arguments and modified the return. But will this break the result?

Comment: Found an answer to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12121687/1828051 and a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/17432089/1828051