# Session Expire Symfony 2 Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, session, authentication

My application uses ajax to request data. I'm using Symfony2, and when the session expires and I make a request with ajax, the login form is shown inside the main area on my application, and not as another view as should be. How can solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating event listener which will be listening for every request:

**services.yml:**

```
your_request_listener:
    class: Acme\AppBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
    arguments: [@security.token_storage]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onRequest }
```

In this event listener I would check for type of request so this would be only Ajax request listener. When request is ajax type then I would check if session has expired - if so, I would create response which will be valid response for ajax request (i.e. `JsonResponse`) and set this response to be sent to user.

```
class RequestListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return; //we dismiss requests other than ajax
        }

        //now you check if user is authenticated/session expired/whatever you need
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if ($token === null) {
            //now you create response which you would expect in your js doing ajax, for example JsonResponse
            $response = new JsonResponse(); //you should give some content here
            $event->setResponse($response); //now you override response which will be sent to user
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [entry point](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points) in which you verify if the request is an AJAX request. If yes, you return a JSON response with 401 HTTP status code. Then in JS code you verify the HTTP status code. If 401, then redirect to login page.

You can read my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378199/symfony2-ajax-request-how-to-handle-authentication-when-needed/31413099#31413099) with the complete solution (see my own answer to my own question). This solution is based on this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428987/what-is-the-best-way-to-notify-a-user-after-an-access-control-rule-redirects/17432089#17432089).