# Symfony AccessDeniedHttpException return 302 code

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

On a Symfony project, I would return sometime an access denied Exception (403 code).
I am doing this through Ajax. But the Exception return a 302 code with the FOS Bundle login page in location.

I isolated the issue on a test function and a test ajax:

PHP

```
  /**
     * @Route("/test")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
     public function testAction() {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
     }
```

JS

```
$.post('/test');
```

This Ajax call return a 302 code and redirect to login page (in response)

How can I solve this "bug"?

EDIT

I add the security.yml

```
main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      true
        provider:       main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            path:       fos_user_security_logout
            target:     /
        remember_me:
            secret:        %secret%
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a simple `kernel.request` listener. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31413099/1832745) for an example of the listener-class, service-configuration, ...

Comment: Or use a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface/9182954#9182954)

Comment: Thanks but this answer is a patch. I could put a kind of false in the return and a condition in JS too but it's not a good practice (of my point of view). And I don't understand the source of the issue

Comment: If returns 302 code to login page then this path is protected by firewall and  the user is not authenticated, checks this in your `security.yml`

Comment: Yonel, Thanks I add the security.yml